# Collapse dualline to centreline only creates outline of dataset using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.0

I'm trying to collapse all divided roads in one centreline and to integrate any other spurs or errors in the dataset to create one set of centrelines. I have used [Merge Divided Roads](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Merge_Divided_Roads_works/00700000003v000000/) but it leaves a lot to be desired (most of the roads I wanted collapsed did not merge).

Here is the dataset:

[image]

And here is what happens when it is collapsed:

[image]

I have also repaired geometry, reprojected and made it into a singlepart feature but nothing seems to work. I have tried it on multiple computers.

Comment: How many features are in this dataset?  To collapse the centerlines you need the individual roads to be features, but your reference to a "singlepart feature" suggests that maybe the dataset is just a single feature, where collapsing will either fail or give strange results.

Comment: whuber - the function won't run unless it's had "multipart to singlepart" feature. It happens even if I don't alter the file

Comment: I suspect you need to merge multipart roads into single parts.  If you merged everything into a single feature, it's amazing the script didn't just fail outright; I doubt it would be able to succeed on something so complex.  Have you tested out the script on a single-part feature representing just one street?

Comment: It isn't a single feature... like I said I used this function: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003r000000

Comment: To clarify: is it, or is it not the case, that your dataset represents *each individual road* as a *single part* feature?  When you ran the collapse-centerline script, how many records were shown in the attribute table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to write something so it is known how it worked out. I ended up being able to get Merged Divided Roads to work, and did not end up using the Collapse tool. Thank you everyone for your help.